# C++ finding index of value in array

Tags: c++

I have recently started working with the Arduino (which is C++).

When I run the below function (along with other code):

```
int index(int val,int list) {
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (val == list[i]) {
          return i;
        }
      return null;
    }
   }
```

I get an error on the line `if (val == list[i]) {`:

```
invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
```

I have two questions: Why is the error happening, and is there some better way to get the index of a value in an array without using complex syntaxes?

Comment: `list` is an `int`, not an array. You can't index it like that.

Comment: Did you mean `int index(int val,int* list)`?

Comment: You're list parameter is just a simple int. You'd want to update this to be an int* or maybe even an std::vector reference. You'd then just need to update the calling code to work with this.

Comment: @WillMoffat **Your**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should accept as an `array` instead of single-variable in function:

```cpp
int index(int val, int *list) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (val == list[i]) {
      return i;
    }    
  }

  /* if no match found */
    return -1;
}
```

Note: you need to return an integer value instead of `null`, since the return type of the function is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as the accepted one, but with more recent c++ features :

```
int index(int val, int *list) 
{
    auto it = std::find(list, list + 8, val);
    if( it == list + 8 )
    {
        return -1; // if no match found
    }
    else
    {
        return distance(list, it);
    }
}
```

Note: you need to return an integer value instead of null, since the return type of the function is int.